# Remove Data Attribute from an element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div tage where in I pass the "Accordion" class. Inside this div, I call a header , wherein I have data attributes:

```
@<div id="@("divMain-" + c.RowKey)" class="accordianCollapsed" style="width: 98%">
    <h2 id="@("h2Main-" + c.RowKey)" data-callid="@c.RowKey" data-fsids="@idCSV">
```

Now when I delete any of the accordion values, I want to delete the data attribute attached to it i.e. one of the fsIDs of the deleted item as well.
 But the problem I am facing is that data is deleted, but when I open the accordion again, the deleted data is repopulated unless refreshed. I do not want to reload my accordion.

So how to remove the data attribute.

I tried the following:

```
$('#h2Main-' + rowkey).removeData(fsID);
```

but it does not work. So I guess I have to delete it from the main data attribute "fsIDs" only.

Any help or solutions will be great.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please provide a copy of your HTML (output from browser please, not source), so we can mock up an example :)

Comment: Again: Please provide a copy of your complete HTML (output from browser please, not source), so we can mock up a working example :)

Answer (score 4):

`removeData` will not remove an attribute.

You need to `removeAttr("data-fsids")`

e.g.

```
$('#h2Main-' + rowkey).removeAttr("data-fsID");
```

If, as your comments indicate, your `data-fsids` attribute has a *list of multiple values*, then you need to get the attribute value, remove the unwanted part and set the attribute back on the element.

e.g.

```
var ids = $('#h2Main-' + rowkey).attr("data-fsID");
ids = removemyunwantedidhere;
$('#h2Main-' + rowkey).attr('data-fsids", ids);
```

Comment: But then data-fsID contains multiple data. So if I want to remove one specific ID from the list, should I still use removeAttr, like it would not remove the data attribute itself.
And also above you have again used removeData only. Can you put in a snippet or something.

Comment: A single `data-` attribute contains a *single string value*. If you have concatenated multiple values into it, please provide an example (you would have to extract the ones you want to keep and replace the attribute value)

Comment: @Siddharth: Tried *what*? My psychic abilities are not what they will be :)

Comment: I tried your code, but the deleted value is still showing up in the accordion when closing and then reopening it.

Comment: And how can I verify that you used my code correctly as my example was obviously incomplete :) can you post an update on your question of what you have *now*?